# Git local branch accessible for coworker

Tags: security, git, version-control, workflow

Bob, Ben and Mike are working on an awesome project.

Bob has created a local branch named foo.
Bob will share branch foo with Ben, so Ben can pull and push to it.
Bob don't want show this branch to Mike.
Bob don't want push this branch to origin.

What is the simplest setup for such scenario ?

Comment: Simplest setup is to fire Mike, since he is clearly untrusted.  Or just wait for him to quit, annoyed that you do not trust him.

Comment: Does Bob not want to show Mike because it's confidential, or just because he doesn't need to see it?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to manage authorization access remains adding an extra layer like **[Gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite)** on your own repo, in order to manage [branch access rights](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/doc/gitolite.conf.mkd#_branches_tags_and_specifying_refex_es).

Answer (score 3):

If these repositories are on the developers local machines, you can:

Give Ben ssh access on Bob's machine and make Bob's repository readable by Ben (it already might be by default). Then Ben runs:

```
git remote add bob bobsmachine.example.com:/path/to/bobs/repo/ursafile
git fetch bob
```

Ben will now have another remote named bob like "origin" that he probably already has.  Ben can do things like:  `git pull bob branchname`

Answer (score 0):

Bob has to push this branch to Ben's local repo.

Comment: How I can setup such environment ? How I can get write access to Ben's repository ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a tool like [Bananajour](https://github.com/toolmantim/bananajour#readme) could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I've found is to create a bare repository on my computer, push whatever branches I want to it, then share that folder and assign permissions using the normal folder sharing built into the operating system.  No extra software to install and learn.  It doesn't scale very well, but it's great for little one-time situations.