# Share a git local branch on AFS with a coworker

Tags: git, version-control

My project uses the Andrew File System (AFS) and Git revision control. I made a clone of the project repository in my sandbox, and have been working on a number of feature requests in their own dedicated local branch.

Before pushing the changes to the main repository, I would like my 2 coworkers to review my changes, and hence, want to share my local branches with them. I searched on the internet and on SO for "git sharing local branch with coworkers", but the most useful solutions suggested pushing changes to the main repository with a unique tag.

Is there any way a coworker could directly read my local branches, without requiring me to push to the main repository? If not, is there some way to push all the branches in one go? There are about 10 branches and I would like to avoid pushing them one by one, if possible.

Moreover, not all 10 branches are relevant to both my coworkers. Unlike this question [Git local branch accessible for coworker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660106/git-local-branch-accessible-for-coworker), I do not mind them accessing the branch shared with the other, but it seems cleaner to tell them which branches I would like them to look at.

Not sure if this is relevant, but they have AFS permissions read and lookup to my sandbox. Also, we do not work in the same location and there is a big timezone difference between us, so checking out one branch at a time for review will take way too long.

Thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your coworkers have read-access to your sandbox, they can simply clone your complete repository (or fetch it into an existing one) and then browse all branches in whatever way they want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am new to Git and did not know it was possible to clone local repositories. I will explore this further.

Comment: All repositories in Git are equal. »remote/global« repositories are just world-readable, they are not very different from local ones.